# How do I make Risk of Rain run in a window with no Border?

Tags: risk-of-rain

I just want to run risk of rain in a window with no border. I already have it in windowed mode, I just need to remove the border. Please help as this is very annoying to me! I can't run in full screen because I'm running a multi-monitor setup and when I click anything on the second display the display with the game on full screen goes to the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the application Borderless Gaming?

https://github.com/Codeusa/Borderless-Gaming

This forces games to run in a borderless window state. I've not tested with Risk of Rain, but have had success with other games with no borderless window mode as native!